# Insert CSS or execute JS based on cookie using google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

I want to show a simple pop-up banner based on if a cookie is present or not. This is the python code I have

```
consent_cookie_str = self.request.cookies.get('consent')
        if not consent_cookie_str:
            // show banner here
```

What is the best way to show the banner if the cookie isn't present? Passing parameters into my jinja template?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      {% if show_alert %}
        alert('You have not given consent!');
      {% endif %}
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And call it from your handler like this (using webapp2):

```
consent_cookie_str = self.request.cookies.get('consent')
show_alert = consent_cookie_str is None
template_values = dict(show_alert=show_alert)
template = JINJA.get_template("page.html")
self.write_html(template.render(template_values))
```

If you are using Flask or something else, should be straightforward to modify this to work for you.